# Resolve Mongo DBRef with Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb, dbref

I use Mongo [DBRef](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/database-references/) with Java driver, but the Mongo client returns a DBRef object instead of a Map object.

```
Document doc = new Document();
doc.append("projectName", "New project");
doc.append("owner", new DBRef("users", owner.get_id()));
client.getDatabase("db").getCollection("projects").insertOne(doc);
```

Then I read the collection

```
MongoCollection<Document> coll = client.getDatabase("db").getCollection("projects");
FindIterable<Document> result = coll.find(query);

BasicDBList list = new BasicDBList();
result.into(list);

return list;
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: You really don't want that. No new project should be using `DBRef`. It may not have been "officially" deprecated from driver support, however no new feature introduced into MongoDB over the last 5 years actually supports it. Instead, simply use `ObjectID` values and define "relationships" within the scope of your "client side code". This is not up to MongoDB to enforce, and `DBRef` never actually did that anyway. Your "modern" tool for obtaining data from "related" collections is [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I'll have a look to $lookup